# php,bootstrap - Modal that has a modal that will update the first modal

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a trouble finding a solution to this. I have a: 
 Page `addBook.php` and `addAuthor.php` 
Table `book` and `author`

`book` has `book_id`, `book_title`, `author_id`,`book_description`
`author` has `author_id`, `author_name` 
 
In my `addBook.php` When I want to add a book, I'll just type in the name, desc etc and `author`. In `author` I'll just simply pull what is inside the author table since it is a foreign key then add it. **IF** the book I want to add have already an author stored in the DB.

Here's the problem.

When I want to add a book without the corresponding `author` there should be a button at the side of the drop down list where it will take me to another modal and let me add an author(It's the `addAuthor.php`), then after saving. It will close and let me go back to the add book where the newly inserted author is in the dropdown.

PS: I have a demo in jsfiddle.net but I don't know how to get the short url.

Comment: Your question need the info from that jsfiddle in your post. Please visit [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and then [edit] your post.

Answer (score 1):

As what i could understand from your question here is an advice:
Use jQuery to change modals. When you are in first modal use on click event on button that should open add author modal. When you click add author button close add book modal and open add author modal with js. After you have added the author when your php scipt confirm author is added again with jquery close add author modal and return back to add book modal, but first add new author in add book modal's dropdown.